# save the results of multiple queries to the same rtk query endpoint

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

I use Redux-Toolkit (RTK) Query. I need to make several requests to one endpoint, because for each request(with unchanged arguments) the server will return another pack with air tickets. How can I save the results of all calls to the `useGetQuery` hook. I need to sort and render all tickets.

```js
const [pollingInterval, setPollingInterval] = useState(1000);

const { data, isError, isLoading } = useGetTicketsQuery(
  searchID,
  {
    pollingInterval,
  }
)

if (data && data.stop && pollingInterval !== 0 ) {
  // if server return "stop", search is over
  setPollingInterval(0);
}
```